# Is an infinite intersection of topology over X a topology?

Tags: general-topology

I know that intersection of any two topology is a topology and so is any finite arbitrary number of intersections. But what about an infinite intersection? I can prove the first two case so if we just do the same proof with the infinite case, would it still be true or would we run into some problems?

Comment: It will be true.

Comment: It's still true, and there is no difference between the proofs. For example, the empty set belongs to all the topologies in your collection (because they are topologies) and so it also belongs to their intersection. Similarly, check the other required axioms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Let $X$ be a nonempty set and $\forall i\in I \; \tau _i$ be a topology on $X$ for an arbitrary indexing set $I$. Then,

1. $(\forall i\in I) \; \; \emptyset \in \displaystyle \bigcap _{i\in I} \tau _i$ and  $X\in \displaystyle \bigcap _{i\in I} \tau _i$ as all of $\tau _i$’s are topology on $X$.
2. Let $U_1, U_2, ..., U_n\in \displaystyle \bigcap _{i\in I} \tau _i$. Then, for all $i\in I$ $\; U_1,...,U_n \in \tau_i$. Then, since all of $\tau_i$’s are topology on $X$, $(\forall i\in I) \; \; U_1\cap U_2 \cap...\cap U_n \in \tau_i $ and so  $U_1\cap U_2 \cap...\cap U_n \in \displaystyle \bigcap _{i\in I} \tau _i$.
3. Let $\{U_j\}_{j\in J}   $ be a collection of some elements of  $\displaystyle \bigcap _{i\in I} \tau _i$. Then, $(\forall i\in I)$ since the collection $ \{U_j\}_{j\in J} $ is in $\tau _i$ and $\tau_i$ is a topology on $X$,  $\; \displaystyle \bigcup _{j\in J}U_j\in \tau_i $. And so,  $\; \displaystyle \bigcup _{j\in J}U_j\in \displaystyle \bigcap _{i\in I} \tau _i$.

As a result, $\displaystyle \bigcap _{i\in I} \tau _i$ is a topology on $X$.